# What is meant by a MSS of 0?

Tags: networking, routing

Am studying and I used the command `netstat -rt` to check  the routing table and understand more about it. The output said that MSS is 0. What is the meaning of this value? Can it also take another value? What is this telling me?

Answer (score 0):

The value zero means that a default value is being used (reference: https://tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-iface.netstat.html).

The default value for MSS is "the device MTU minus headers" (reference: the `route(8)` manual on Ubuntu), which is 536 bytes for IPv4 or 1220 bytes for IPv6 (reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size).

See also [RFC876, "The TCP Maximum Segment Size and Related Topics"](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc879.txt).

Comment: thank you very much